# Schema.org for links to member organizations

Tags: seo, schema.org, rel

I'm finishing up a site for a client who is a member of multiple organizations and wants to display links to those organizations on their website as in:

> Client Company is a Proud Member of:
>
> Organization 1
>
> Organization 2, etc.

I've never really dealt with this situation before and maybe I'm just not phrasing my question properly, but I'm not finding anything. It leaves me with a couple of questions:

1. Is there an appropriate schema in existence for this scenario?
2. Is there an appropriate `rel` attribute that I should be using?
3. Will these links help or hurt SEO in any way?

Comment: Just use multiple http://schema.org/Organization each organization would be it's own itemscope and that's perfectly fine to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No specific Schema for multiple organisations but the available markup for [organisation Schema](http://schema.org/Organization) can handle this.
2. No (see below example markup).
3. Schema markup won't make any difference to the rankings of web pages in Google's index (SEO) however could entice click through for any rich snippets from information that the Schema markup provides a search engine.

**Example**

Directory of football teams:-

```
<!-- Team One -->
<li class="team">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsTeam">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example1.com">
            <div itemprop="name">
                <strong>Manchester United</strong>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div itemprop="description">This is the description for Manchester United.</div>
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">Old Trafford Stadium, Sir Matt Busby Way</span><br>
            P.O. Box: <span itemprop="postOfficeBoxNumber">123</span><br>
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">Manchester</span><br>
            <span itemprop="addressRegion">Greater Manchester</span><br>
            <span itemprop="postalCode">M16 0RA</span><br>
            <span itemprop="addressCountry">United Kingdom</span><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

<!-- Team Two -->
<li class="team">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsTeam">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example2.com">
            <div itemprop="name">
                <strong>Arsenal</strong>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div itemprop="description">This is the description for Arsenal.</div>
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">Emirates Stadium, Hornsey Road</span><br>
            P.O. Box: <span itemprop="postOfficeBoxNumber">123</span><br>
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">London</span><br>
            <span itemprop="addressRegion">North London</span><br>
            <span itemprop="postalCode">N5 1BU</span><br>
            <span itemprop="addressCountry">United Kingdom</span><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your client ([→ `LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness)) is a member ([→ `member`](http://schema.org/member)) of an organization ([→ `Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization)).

So in Microdata the structure could look like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <!-- client company -->
  <div itemprop="member" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><!-- organization 1 --></div>
  <div itemprop="member" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><!-- organization 2 --></div>
</div>
```

Search engines *might* do various things with this information, e.g., enhancing the display of your search result. There is no reason to assume that it could hurt in any way (unless you are spamming/lying).

A link type (e.g., as value for the `rel` attribute) could only be used for links to the organization websites. Apart from `external` (which you could use [for every link not pointing to a page of your website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638774/1591669)), I can’t think of a link type that could be used here. There is a [Microformat "group" proposal](http://microformats.org/wiki/group-brainstorming), which uses the `member` link type, but it’s not valid in HTML5.